# RestKit nested mapping to specific array item

Tags: ios, core-data, mapping, restkit

It is possible to force the RestKit object mapper to map to a specific nested object in an array via the mapKeyPath dot syntax?

Here's the response I am trying to map

```
<result is_array="true">
  <item>
     <_field_data>
        <nid>
           <entity>
              <field_region>
                 <und is_array="true">
                    <item>
                       <value>1</value>
                    </item>
                 </und>
              </field_region>
....
```

I am only interested in the first item that will ever be returned for field_region.

What is the correct manner to map this?

I have tried various iterations of:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *record = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyRecordClass class] inManagedObjectStore:objManager.objectStore];
[record mapKeyPath:@"_field_data.nid.entity.field_region.und.0.item.value" toAttribute:@"region"];
```

and i keep getting errors akin to:

```
T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:152 Found transformable value at keyPath '_field_data.nid.entity.field_region.und.0.item.value'. Transforming from type '__NSArrayI' to 'NSNumber'
W restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:232 Failed transformation of value at keyPath '_field_data.nid.entity.field_region.und.0.item.value'. No strategy for transforming from '__NSArrayI' to 'NSNumber'
```

I invoke the mapping via:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:kMyResourcePath usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
    loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[MyRecordClass class]];
    loader.method = RKRequestMethodGET;
    loader.delegate = self;
    loader.targetObject = nil;
}];
```

Any ideas? Most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

think you'll have to have mapping for every level, so entity object mapping contains a field region object.  field region object mapping contains a und object.  und object mapping contains item, etc...

I've only done this with nested json rest kit responses, not xml, but had to create mapping for each level.

something like this (granted this is incomplete because you'd need a relation for every level)

```
RKObjectMapping* undMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[UND class]];
[und mapKeyPath:@"item" toAttribute:@"item"];

RKObjectMapping* regionmapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Region class]]; 
[regionmapping mapKeyPath:@"und" toRelationship:@"undArrays" withMapping:undMapping];
```

Comment: thanks. i looked into this mapping within mapping, but thought it wiser (and easier) to simplify the server response.